# I have a problem in sass, why the variable not understandable for lang['en'] but in case selector is ok

Tags: variables, sass, register-transfer-level

```
[lang='en'] { $left:left;  $right:right; }
[lang='ar'] { $left:right; $right:left; }
```

[image: example for problem]

Why am I getting error in first one?

Comment: the fist one already worked, but not worked in case variables only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your variable `$left` is undefined in the *global* context. You only defined it in the context of `[lang='en']` and `[lang='ar']`.

As sass [variables](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables) are *imperative*, you can initiate it with a default value and overwrite it later.

Comment: when declared them in this case, the value is taken from the default value not in case lang['en'] or lang['ar']. (I mean the overwrite not happen)

$left: left !default;
$right:right !default;

[lang='en'] {
  $left:left; 
  $right:right;
}
[lang='ar'] {
  $left:right; 
  $right:left;
}

Comment: That is a problem with your nesting. How does the html look?

Comment: sorry, no error in html, but it prints the value of default value not that found in lang['en']

Comment: How does the structure of your html look? Your `[lang]` selector is not getting applied. I guess something like `[lang='en'] { p { $left:left;  $right:right; } }` could fix it.

Comment: I dont  want to specify selector , I need in general in app any left is right and the right is left , I userd * like this [lang='en'] { * { $left:left;  $right:right; } } 
In general I applied your code but the result is not correct, still the problem now is only the value of variable is taken from default value

Comment: Well the question was what caused the error and my answer clearly solved that error, so it should be accepted. You should make another question with your current problem and specify it with code examples, so that people can understand it and help you.

Comment: your answer is correct by 50%, there is no syntax error only, but still there is runtime error